# Jolt transformation to get upper level field

Tags: json, jolt

I need to do a jolt transformation. I've tried a lot of ways and I can't get what I want, despite it looking quite simple.

Here is the original JSON :

```
{
  "promoted_by": {
    "display_value": "useless_value",
    "value": "value_1"
  },
  "parent": {
    "display_value": "useless_value",
    "value": "value_2"
  }
}
```

I need to have this JSON :

```
{
  "promoted_by": "value_1"
  "parent": "value_2"
}
```

Basically take the "value" field and put it in a field called like the upper level field.
I have found something like :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "???"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But I can't find a way to get the upper level field name.
Can someone tell me how to do that ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need **`&`** wildcard to replicate the value with **`1`** grabbing from one upper level, eg **`&1`** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I could use "&1"